# Xcode profiling error, missing lib?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, profiling

I already tried to find similar errors on the internet, but it seems that I am the only one getting this error.

What I do is, when I want to start profiling my application in Xcode, it crashes after compiling the app. In the settings I already edited the scheme to use the "debug" build but that changed nothing.

The crash report shows this particular error message. I already tried to figure it out on my own, but currently I am stuck. All I want is to see how much memory my application uses and what it does with the memory.

Here the error message. Hope you are able to help me somehow:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
>   Reason: image not found

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when running `instruments` for end-to-end tests:

`$ instruments -s devices
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsPlugIn
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/../../..//DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10A0DF000, size=0x00005000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/../../..//DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks//DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10A0ED000, size=0x00005000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks//DTBinaryAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/DTBinaryAnalysis
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Solution (funny enough): reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall xcode from scratch and see if it helps you.

That should do the trick. The installation normally should install all kind of instruments for xcode.